# Springboot test not connecting to database in github CI

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, github-ci

I am trying to set up github CI workflow to do my springboot application tests. However the test are failing on database connection, even though locally it works fine.

The CI job is as follow

```
  build:
# The type of runner that the job will run on
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

# Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: Prepare test database
    run: docker-compose -f docker-compose-test.yaml up -d
  - name: Wait for the database to start
    run: wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eficode/wait-for/$WAIT_FOR_VERSION/wait-for | sh -s -- localhost:55001 -- echo "Database is up"
    env:
      WAIT_FOR_VERSION: 4df3f9262d84cab0039c07bf861045fbb3c20ab7 # v2.2.3
  - name: Set up JDK 17
    uses: actions/setup-java@v3
    with:
      java-version: '17'
      distribution: 'temurin'
  - name: Validate Gradle wrapper
    uses: gradle/wrapper-validation-action@e6e38bacfdf1a337459f332974bb2327a31aaf4b

  - name: Make gradlew executable
    run: chmod +x gradlew

  - name: Build with Gradle
    run: ./gradlew build
```

Docker compose test

```
services:
  db-test-database:
    image: mysql:5.5
    ports:
      - "55001:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbTest
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw
```

To configure the database within tests I use projectroot/test/resources/application.yml

```
spring:
 datasource:
   url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:55001/dbTest
   username: root
   password: my-secret-pw
   driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

But the smoke test (@SpringBootTest with autowire) fails on, suggesting not being able to connect to the database:

```
AppSmokeTest > contextLoads() FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804
        Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException at AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421
            Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException at SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112
                Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException at SQLError.java:174
                    Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException at NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2
                        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException at Net.java:-2
```

Could anyone point me to what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the end when running on CI it did not pick the configuration for test from test/resources/application.yaml. (Which I found by building with --debug and checking for jdbcurl)

The solution was to move the configuration to main/resources/application-test.yaml